# Python: new instance of variable is not created in new instance of class

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization

I have found strange Python's behavior (or probably I don't understand how inheritance and/or default values of attributes works).

For given code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
        print "in init", self.s

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, s = set()):
        super(B, self).__init__(s)
        print "after super", self.s
        self.s.add('foo')
        print '--------------'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = B()
    b = B()
```

I get following output:

```
in init set([])
after super set([])
--------------
in init set(['foo']) # Why it has value set in other object?!
after super set(['foo'])
--------------
```

Of course desired behavior would be to init self.s in second object (b) with an empty set, but for unknown reason it gets state from previous object. Why does it happen? How to obtain desired behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really explanatory!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've fallen prey to the mutable default argument trap. The `set()` that you specified as the default in B's `__init__` is the same object that will be passed to each new `B` that you create. Putting it into `self` doesn't make a new copy, it just creates a reference to the same object.

You probably want to make a copy in each new object, so do it explicitly:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = copy.copy(s)
```

Comment: Using `copy()` works in this particular case, though the most common Python pattern is to use `None` as the default, as I give an example of below.

Comment: @MattGood, I made my recommendation based on a gut feeling that a copy would be most appropriate even when an explicit argument was given. It's unusual for an object to hold and modify a reference to something outside of itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a default for an argument, the value is computed at the time you *define* the function, not when you call it.  So, it's using the same `set()` that was created when you defined the class, and adding more and more items to it.

Instead, the typical Python pattern is to use `None` as the default, and then explicitly initialize a new `set()` (or list, dict, or any object you want) within the body of `__init__`.

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, s=None):
    if s is None:
      s = set()
```